# Flink readCsvFile method with pojoTypes

Tags: java, casting, apache-flink, pojo

I have the following code in my flink project:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // set up the execution environment
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataSet<Event> events =
            env.readCsvFile(args[0]).pojoType(
               Event.class,
               "time",
               "vid",
               "speed",
               "xWay",
               "lane",
               "dir",
               "seg",
               "pos"
            );

        System.out.println("----> " + events.count());
    }
}
```

And this is the class `Event`:

```java
class Event {
    public int time;
    public int vid;
    public int speed;
    public int xWay;
    public int lane;
    public int dir;
    public int seg;
    public int pos;

    public Event() { }

    public Event(int time_in, int vid_in, int speed_in, int xWay_in, int lane_in, int dir_in, int seg_in, int pos_in) {
        this.time = time_in;
        this.vid = vid_in;
        this.speed = speed_in;
        this.xWay = xWay_in;
        this.lane = lane_in;
        this.dir = dir_in;
        this.seg = seg_in;
        this.pos = pos_in;
    }
}
```

The project compiles but when I run it, there is an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.PojoTypeInfo
```

The CSV file has 8 integer values separated by a comma in each line.

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/index.html) has the following example:

```
DataSet<Person>> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("hdfs:///the/CSV/file")
                     .pojoType(Person.class, "name", "age", "zipcode");
```

I don't know if the POJO definition is wrong, surely it is. I achieved what I wanted using `map` and `readTextFile` but this could be more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassCastException` is a bug that will be fixed [soon](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/5097) and replaced by a more meaningful exception. `Event` is a `GenericType` instead of a `PojoType`. I think the reason might be that `Event` is member class instead of a global accessible class. Adding the `static` modifier should solve the problem.

Comment: The problem was that the class wasn't `public`. Adding it solves the problem